# Android. How to show button to top of keyboard when it's opened?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I need to show my button to top of soft keyboard (when it's opened). For this I implement this https://medium.com/@madalinnita/android-how-to-move-views-above-keyboard-when-its-opened-quick-secure-solution-90188c4d7b15.

My layout structure:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <EditText..../>
           <EditText..../>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:gravity="end"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And everything working fine, but in small devices my button covers edit text. Is it possible to fix it? I don't have any ideas. I need to somehow make the button and keyboard appear under edit text even on small devices.

Please, help me.

Comment: One option is to wrap the view inside a scrollview and then the user could scroll down to the button when the keyboard is open.

Comment: @Alban Gashi, do you mean wrap the button inside a scrollview ?

Comment: i think he means you put the parent view inside of a scroll view maybe a constraint layout or whatever layout you're using then you put that whole view inside of a scrollview. You constraint the scrollview to the bottom parent and when the soft keyboard is opened the view will scroll downwards or the user can scroll downwards to reach the button

Comment: @testivanivan sorry for not being precise in the suggestion. Brandon explained what I meant.

Comment: @Alban Gashi, could you show with an example please? Since it didn't work for me, maybe I misunderstood your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your whole view inside a ScrollView which would then allow you to scroll the view while the keyboard is open.
In this example I am using a LinearLayout you can use other layouts as well.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And add to your Manifest for the specific activity this line of code:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line -> `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, in your current activity tag in Manifest as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        ...>
        
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            ...
            />
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```